# Django run windows command prompt

Tags: python, django, django-views, subprocess, command-prompt

How i can show/run windows command prompt using django ?

in my view.

```
def run(request):

    cmd = '__batch.cmd Server.Tester.exe Config.xml'
    exitcode = str(subprocess.call(cmd, shell=False))

    return render(request, "testy/lista.html", {"exitcode": exitcode})
```

i use **subprocess.call** but output see in **pycharm terminal** not in **windows command prompt**. Can someone help me ?

[image]

Comment: This question doesn't make sense. Where would you show it? Django is a web framework, users access it via Web browsers.

Comment: This application is run only on local machine and view must run .exe  file. I need show command prompt, but this external app requires interact yes/no.